# How to detect long press event to drag and rearrange elements in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-touch

I have an ng-repeat through which I am displaying students cards.

I just want to rearrange their order as specified in question.

In what way I can do it?

Comment: user angular 'filter'

Comment: you can jquery drag and drop along with ng-repeat for this

Comment: To handle long press try this directive https://gist.github.com/BobNisco/9885852

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi jquery  plugins along angular is not good idea

Comment: how come ? he can do it by making a directive. Mixing will be held there @levi

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi ahhh, using a directive,  yes, I tough u mean using a jquery plugin directly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ngDraggable library. ng-drag-data automatically detect long press